# php retrieve filename from database

Tags: php, sql, file

I'm trying to retrieve a filename from a database from table `HORSE` and column `HORSE_IMAGE`

```
$path = "horse_images/".$row["HORSE_IMAGE"];
$query = "DELETE FROM HORSE WHERE HORSE_ID=".$_GET["horseno"]." AND HORSE_IMAGE=".$row["HORSE_IMAGE"];
```

Currently `HORSE_IMAGE` returns nothing, but if I change it to `HORSE_ID` or `HORSE_NAME`, it works.

i.e. If i echo `$row["HORSE_NAME"]` it returns "You Beauty".

If I look up the row in the database I can see the filename `shop-1.jpg` is there.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are asking about retrieving something from a database but you are showing a delete query!? What are you doing there?

Comment: If `horse_id` is the PK of the table, it must be unique, so, for deleting a row, you don't need the second condition with `horse_image`. Am I right?

Comment: Also note that you are totally susceptible to SQL injection with this type of code, and you should really be using parameterized statements in this case (especially on a DELETE).

Comment: Sorry my vocab its sub-par, I have already retrieved the set i needed earlier, now I'm deleting a specific image. By retrieve I meant get $row["HORSE_IMAGE"], but it was returning nothing.

Comment: I'm not trying to delete the whole row, I'm just trying to delete the HORSE_IMAGE column, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: use `DELETE` only when you want to delete entire row, use `UPDATE` instead if you want to `NULL` some column.

Comment: `I'm not trying to delete the whole row, I'm just trying to delete the HORSE_IMAGE column, am I doing it wrong?` the **column** or the **value of the field in that row**? You really need to get some basic context... (by the way, you're doing it wrong in both cases)

Comment: If you want to change a single column of a row, use an UPDATE statement. DELETE is for removing complete rows only.

And yes, escape anything before using it in your query.

"UPDATE HORSE SET HORSE_IMAGE = NULL WHERE HORSE_ID=".(int)$_GET["horseno"].";

Comment: Yep, i got it working last night, thanks to the comments. One of you put it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change a single column of a row, use an UPDATE statement. DELETE is for removing complete rows only. And yes, escape anything before using it in your query.

```
"UPDATE HORSE SET HORSE_IMAGE = NULL WHERE HORSE_ID=".(int)$_GET["horseno"];
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the question, ToBe's answer might be correct, but you really should consider using PDO for MySql queries, in order to prevent Sql injection.
Try:

```
<?php

  $query = "UPDATE HORSE SET HORSE_IMAGE = NULL WHERE HORSE_ID = ?";

  $db = new PDO(dsn, username, password);
  $prep = $db->prepare($query);

  $res = $prep->execute(array((int)$_GET["horseno"]));

?>
```

Take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Comment: You are definetly right, my somewhat lazy escaping of "horseno" works, but the PDO approach might be better on the long run for anything more sophisticated. (I just dont like PDO ;) )